# Problems installing matplotlib for python in windows 10

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

Everytime I try to install the matplotlib package for python in windows 10, it generates the following errors. I downloaded `matplotlib-1.5.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl` file in windows prompt and here are the errors it generate:

```
C:\Users\Pentazoid\Downloads>pip install --upgrade pip
 Collecting pip
   Downloading pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
     100% |################################| 1.3MB 381kB/s
 Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 8.1.1
     Uninstalling pip-8.1.1:
        Successfully uninstalled pip-8.1.1
  Exception:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\pentazoid\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32  \lib\shutil.py", line 381, in _rmtree_unsafe
     os.unlink(fullname)
 PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\PENTAZ~1 \\AppData     \\Local\\Temp\\pip-nvouvrx2-uninstall\\users\\pentazoid\\appdata \\local     \\programs\\python\\python35-32\\scripts\\pip.exe'

     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\users\pentazoid\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32    \lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 209, in main
      logger.critical(
     File "c:\users\pentazoid\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32  \lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 317, in run
          File "c:\users\pentazoid\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 743, in install
     File "c:\users\pentazoid\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32 \lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 759, in commit_uninstall
     self.uninstalled.rollback()
     File "c:\users\pentazoid\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_uninstall.py", line 142, in commit
      rmtree(self.save_dir)
   File "c:\users\pentazoid\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32  \lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
    return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "c:\users\pentazoid\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32 \lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 212, in call
   raise attempt.get()
  File "c:\users\pentazoid\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 247, in get
    six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
     File "c:\users\pentazoid\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\users\pentazoid\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 200, in call
    attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
  File "c:\users\pentazoid\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 102, in rmtree
     onerror=rmtree_errorhandler)
  File "c:\users\pentazoid\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32  \lib\shutil.py", line 488, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "c:\users\pentazoid\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32   \lib\shutil.py", line 378, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
   File "c:\users\pentazoid\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32 \lib\shutil.py", line 378, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "c:\users\pentazoid\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32 \lib\shutil.py", line 378, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
   File "c:\users\pentazoid\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\shutil.py", line 378, in _rmtree_unsafe
     _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
   File "c:\users\pentazoid\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\shutil.py", line 378, in _rmtree_unsafe
     _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
    File "c:\users\pentazoid\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\shutil.py", line 378, in _rmtree_unsafe
      _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
    File "c:\users\pentazoid\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\shutil.py", line 378, in _rmtree_unsafe
     _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
    File "c:\users\pentazoid\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\shutil.py", line 378, in _rmtree_unsafe
     _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
    File "c:\users\pentazoid\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\shutil.py", line 383, in _rmtree_unsafe
      onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
    File "c:\users\pentazoid\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 114, in rmtree_errorhandler
       func(path)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\PENTAZ~1 \\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-nvouvrx2-uninstall\\users\\pentazoid\\appdata\\local    \\programs\\python\\python35-32\\scripts\\pip.exe'
```

I am using Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32, but the `matplotlib-1.5.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl`  seems to be the only available matplotlib package for the version of python I have

Comment: Try running the command-line as an administrator

Comment: Thanks, that worked